# switch div's with the same name css jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, swap

I have 2 div's with the same name as below (I can not rename the divs unfortunately).

How can I switch the 2 'nav' div's, so that the 1st one appears above the other?

Example:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="nav"> ... </div>
   <div class="nav"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Just incase you wonder, this is put together via a CMS - so I have to nav's, both with the same class name. But I want the 1st one (div) to appear before the 2nd one.

CSS or jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select them with CSS using:

```
/* first .nav */
.main .nav:first-child { ... }
.main .nav:nth-child(1) { ... }

/* second .nav */
.main .nav:nth-child(2) { ... }
.main .nav:last-child { .. } /* will select the LAST .nav */
```

EDIT bases on your comment.

Hide the second `.nav` using `display: none`, then make this jQuery function (please note that I'm no jQuery hero):

```
$(".swapIt").click(function() {
    if( $(".main .nav:nth-child(1)").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".main .nav:nth-child(1)").hide();
        $(".main .nav:nth-child(2)").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".main .nav:nth-child(2)").hide();
        $(".main .nav:nth-child(1)").show();        
    }
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/6Z62m/)

Comment: I would prefer to use CSS - but how do I swap using your above example?

Comment: Depends, how do you load the first or the second menu, or is it triggered by a button? Could you clarify how you want it to function?

Comment: It is triggered by a button and I need the first menu ul swapped and put below the 2nd. see here: http://screencast.com/t/Disjcqck1Q

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kYUmr/1/)

```
$('.main .nav:first-child').appendTo('.main');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) selector:

```
$( ".main" ).first().css( "z-index", "1000" );
```

Comment: Before - not in front of.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('.main .nav:eq(0)').before($('.main .nav:eq(1)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

can select the first div with class nav like this :

```
$( ".main .nav" ).first();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/kYUmr/)